# jscript/html popup at specifc time

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm trying to setup a popup message at a specific time on all weekdays and saturdays. Should be fairly simple, and I'm aware that this could be done using arrays and so on, but please bear with me, as i'm kinda new to this.

What I have so far, looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var day = day.getday();
var hr = day.getHours();

if ((hr < 10) && (hr > 18) && (day == 1) || (hr < 10) && (hr > 18) && (day == 2) || (hr < 10) && (hr > 18) && (day == 3) || (hr < 10) && (hr > 18) && (day == 4) || (hr < 10) && (hr > 18) && (day == 5))

{
document.write("test");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, first of all don't use <br> tags in  <script> tags. And yes could be an object of specific times on a days and  it's could be made with a function method so it will save your time

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I do however know that - obviously those weren't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a messy example that shows an approach that you can take...  Not all code-paths are completed (*like hooking up the event for tomorrow if the connfigured hour/min is already passed*) but...it does show a message at a configured hour/min of the day if that day is any day other than Sunday.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var showPopup = function()
    {
        document.write("test");
        alert("Show Message!");
    };

    var hookupAlert = function(targetHour, targetMin)
    {
        var nextAlert = null;
        var now = new Date();       // Now.
        var day = now.getDay();     // Returns 0-6 where 0=Sunday, 6=Saturday.
        var hr = now.getHours();    // Returns 0-23.
        var min = now.getMinutes(); // Returns 0-59.

        // If a weekday or saturday.
        if(day != 0)
        {
            // Is it before the target hour/min?
            if(hr <= targetHour && min < targetMin)
            {
                nextAlert = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), targetHour, targetMin, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                // We've passed the target hour/min for the day...
                // TODO: Possibly determine tomorrow (or if tomorrow is Sunday, the day after).
                console.log("Passed the targetHour & targetMin for the day.");
            }
        }

        if(nextAlert)
        {
            var diffInMs = Math.abs(nextAlert - now);
            window.setTimeout(showPopup, diffInMs);
        }
    };


    // Make the call to hook up the alert at 11:15.
    hookupAlert(11, 15);    // Hour between 0-23, Min between 0-59.


</script>

</body>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, MJS. Helped me in the right direction. Appreciate it.